# Intellij - New Module from existing Sources : nothing happen

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14, spring-initializr

I am using . I have created an emty project with jdk 17 and I have downloaded a project from spring initialzr, I have tried to import it inside my project but nothing appear after clicking of File -> New -> Module from existing source.

Windows 11, JDK 17.

Intellij version :

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.4 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-222.4459.24, built on November 22, 2022
Licensed to khalid tounoussi
Subscription is active until September 27, 2023.
For educational use only.
Runtime version: 17.0.5+7-b469.71 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 11 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2016M
Cores: 8
Non-Bundled Plugins:
    com.tabnine.TabNine (0.8.7)
    com.jinsihou.react.snippets (1.1.1)
    org.intellij.plugins.junitgen (2.0.12)
    com.poratu.idea.plugins.tomcat (4.3.8)
    com.jetbrains.jax.ws (222.4459.16)
    com.intellij.spring.batch (222.4459.16)
    com.github.setial (4.0.2)
    GrepConsole (12.15.211.6693.1)
    com.intellij.lang.jsgraphql (3.3.0)
    com.yiycf.plugins.mavenDependencyHelper (2.5)
    com.haulmont.jpab (2022.5.2-222)
    MavenRunHelper (4.23.222.2964.0)

Kotlin: 222-1.7.10-release-334-IJ4459.24
```

I have tried to open first the project in intellj ( the project that I have download it from spring initliazr ) and it works fine.
I have excluded windows defender from analysing all the folders of the project.

If I use spring initialzr for building projects in intellj, it works fine.

Comment: Check if the problem reproduces in the 2022.3 build from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download. If the problem remains, contact JetBrains support at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new and provide the IDE logs. (Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data)